# Is there a way to `Exec` an dependency artifact?

Tags: java, gradle

So, here is my dilemma. I am building with gradle, and need to generate some protobuf classes. I know that there is a plugin for that, but it only works with gradle 2.12+, and that makes my build more than twice slower than the one I am using (2.8), so I don't want to upgrade.

I made a task like this:

```
task protoc << {    
  exec {
    commandLine = ['protoc', "--proto_path", "${projectDir}/src/main/proto", "--java_out", "src/gen/main/java"] + protoFiles
  }
}
```

and it works ... but now I have to tell everybody who wants to build to install `protoc` first. 
There is a maven artifact here: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protoc
that apparently provides the executable, but I can't figure out how to tell gradle to download that and then execute. I know how to do it for a `javaexec` but not for a non-java executable.

Is there some magic incantation I can use here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should work:

```
plugins {
  id "com.google.osdetector" version "1.3.1"
}

repositories {
  jcenter()
}

configurations {
  protoc    
}

dependencies {
  protoc "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.1.0:${osdetector.classifier}@exe"
}

task executeProtoc(type: Exec) {
  executable configurations.protoc.singleFile
  args "--proto_path", "${projectDir}/src/main/proto"
  args "--java_out", "src/gen/main/java"
  args protoFiles
}
```

Comment: I had to change this to `commandLine = [configurations.protoc.singleFile, "--proto_path", "${projectDir}/src/main/proto" ..]` - the way you wrote it failed for me for some reason ("Missing input file" - looks like protoc wasn't getting the args)  ... Not sure why, I gave up long time ago trying to figure out logic behind gradle's syntax, just use whatever works :) 
Otherwise, worked great! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hmm ... I guess, I spoke too soon :(
It worked for me locally, but now I am getting this on jenkins: `Cannot run program "/home/jenkins/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.protobuf/protoc/2.6.1/49565269d355231128f9689f0cc050725bcea6fd/protoc-2.6.1-linux-x86_64.exe" : error=13, Permission denied`

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably you should set executable flag for this file on linux platform :) Try to add something like:
 `doFirst {Runtime.runtime.exec("chmod +x " + configurations.protoc.singleFile)}` in task section

Comment: Or even more simple: `doFirst{ ant.chmod(perm: "+x", file: configurations.protoc.singleFile) }`, but I didn't test it. Please write if it works on linux and correctly ignores windows :)

Comment: I am blessed to not have windows anywhere within my reach :)

Comment: The thing is, it doesn't happen on every build. Looks like it fails only when I hit a new worker, that hasn't downloaded the artifact before. Seems like some kind of a race condition :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
import org.gradle.internal.os.OperatingSystem

apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    protoc    
}


dependencies {

    Map platformMapping = [
            (OperatingSystem.WINDOWS) : 'windows-x86_32',
            (OperatingSystem.MAC_OS) : 'osx-x86_32'
    ].withDefault { 'linux-x86_32' }

    protoc "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.1.0:${platformMapping.get(OperatingSystem.current())}@exe"
}

task copyProtoc(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.protoc
    into "$buildDir/protoc"
}
```